# SQL: find most common values for specific members in column 1

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL related question:

Let us assume I have the following simple data table:

[image]

I would like to identify the most common street address and place it in column 3:

[image]

I think this should be fairly straight-forward using COUNT? Not quite sure how to go about it though. Any help is greatly appreciated

Regards

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You also might want to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2):

This is a very long method that I just wrote. It only lists the most frequent address. You have to get these values and insert them into the table. See if it works for you:

```
select * from

(select d.company, count(d.address) as final, c.maxcount,d.address
from dbo.test d inner join

(select a.company,max(a.add_count) as maxcount from

(select company,address,count(address) as add_count  from dbo.test group by company,address)a


group by a.company) c
on (d.company = c.company)



group by d.company,c.maxcount,d.address)e
where e.maxcount=e.final
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query in standard SQL. It first counts records per company and address, then ranks them per company giving the most often occurring address rank #1. Then it only keeps those best ranked address records, joins with the table again and shows the results.

```
select
  mytable.company,
  mytable.address,
  ranked.address as most_common_address
from mytable 
join
(
  select
    company,
    address,
    row_number() over (partition by company oder by cnt desc) as rn
  from
  (
    select
      company,
      address,
      count(*) over (partition by company, address) as cnt
    from mytable
  ) counted
) ranked on ranked.rn = 1
         and ranked.company = mytable.company
         and ranked.address = mytable.address;
```

Comment: This sort of thing should work in most databases but if you are using mySQl , it will not as it does not have windowing functions. This is why it is critical to always specify the database backend when asking a SQL question as many solutions only work for specific databases.

Comment: @HLGEM: I agree. I thought I'd post this answer nonetheless (and the Oracle answer, too), as even if the OP uses a DBMS not featuring window functions, my answers may at least help future readers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This select statement will give you the most frequent occurrence. **Let us call this A**.

```
SELECT       `value`,
         COUNT(`value`) AS `value_occurrence` 
    FROM     `my_table`
    GROUP BY `value`
    ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
    LIMIT    1;
```

To **INSERT** this into your table,

```
INSERT INTO db (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, A)
```

Note that you want that whole select statment for A!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your DBMS. Here is a solution for Oracle.

```
select
  company,
  address,
  (
    select stats_mode(address) 
    from mytable this_company_only
    where this_company_only.company = mytable.company
  ) as most_common_address
from mytable;
```

This looks a bit clumsy, because `STATS_MODE` is only available as an aggregate function, not as an analytic window function.